# Is it possible to use the PhysFS library with encrypted zip files?

Tags: encryption, zip

Is it possible to use the PhysFS library to read and write encrypted zip files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the website, there's no mention of encryption. Therefore, you'd probably have to decrypt the zip file first.